# How to generate file selection window in button click?

Tags: asp.net

I want to open file selection window, when button clicked.

How can I open file selection window without using File uploader control?

Comment: There is one way if you really want to show Button to user, You can put Button control on Fileupload Control (Handle this in HTML), You have to handle manually using Javascript. I did this in one project, But I don't have code right now.

Comment: Are you doing this for styling.

Comment: @Power Star, Power Star sreenivaasan :), can u upload that code later??

Comment: I have a doubt in your requirement. Do you asking button for styling? Why you not preferring file upload control? :)

Comment: @ Power Star, yes its for styling..fileuploader not good for ma style

Comment: @Power Star, are you from India?? especially from TamilNadu??

Comment: Then i will give you solution for styling. Is this feasible?

Comment: Ya ya! I am from Tamil Nadu.

Comment: @Power Star,ok    help me

Comment: @Power Star, I felt through  ur name power star :);)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted updated fiddle. This will help you!

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="upload">
        <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
div.upload {
    width: 157px;
    height: 57px;
    background: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dqTIJRTqEAQ/UJaofTQm3hI/AAAAAAAABHo/w7ruR1SOIsA/s157/upload.png);
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.upload input[type=file] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 157px !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Isakkiraj/mxq9R/4632/

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter options and filter index.
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
         openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // Process input if the user clicked OK.

    }
```

Please mark answer as right if it helpful to you.

Comment: It is for Windows applications.

Comment: sorry brother my one is web application